# Hibernate tool, auto cascade all

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, jboss-tools

I have a database and I generated all bean and *hbm.xml* files with hibernate tool.

I noticed this tool not generated automatically the cascade property... I read it can be done using *reveng.xml*.

There are ways to auto-generate *revenge.xml*, or set a cascade property 1 time for all tables?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options for the auto property:

- `create` - It creates new tables corresponding mapping or annotation. It drops existing tables and data.
- `update` - It keeps existing data and tables. It updates the schema.
  here we have to take care contracts.
- `create-drop` - It is same like create but once session gets closed it
  drops everything.
- `validate` - it validates or matches schema with map or annotation.
  It's valid for a Production environment.

Propery `hbm2ddl.auto = update` in configuration xml.

If you want to delete cascade you should add to your collection in XML the following:

```
cascade="delete-orphan" 
cascade="save-update, delete"
```